# Formatting issue with CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting

I have a website that has a moving background (code borrowed somewhere online) and I recently corrected an issue with the scroll bar not appearing but that actually caused another issue that wasn't very noticeable until I tried adding a new page.

If you go to http://theromdepot.com/ and move your cursor to the bottom of the page, you'll see a very thin white line start to appear. I just ignored it until I started adding a new page here: http://theromdepot.com/emulators.php. Now you can really see the issue. I'm sure the problem is in my CSS, but for some reason I cannot find it. I'd really appreciate any help, thanks.

CSS: http://pastebin.com/Up3WtmJ8

emulators.php: http://pastebin.com/UE78eMgT

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem really lies in the CSS,but not just in it. I am not pretty sure what's the exact problem,but I ran the developer tools with Internet explorer and I have discovered this:

[image]

If you leave out the `transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);` property,the problem won't persist anymore.